# Fcitx doesn't work on Opera web browser

Tags: input-language, fcitx

as i mentioned via title, i couldn't either type Vietnamese or switch to Vietnamese input method in Opera web browser. Everything run correctly except it. I ran "fcitx-diagnose" command and found somethings like "**Cannot find `gtk-query-immodules` for gtk 2**, **Cannot find fcitx im module for gtk 2.**...". I tried many way such as:
- install fcitx-libs-dev
- remove then reinstall
- add parameter to ~/.profile.
But it still haven't worked

Comment: What's the output of this command: `env | grep -E 'XMOD|_IM'`

Comment: Also, which desktop environment are you on?

Comment: I'm using Kubuntu 19.04.

Comment: GTK_IM_MODULE=fcitx
QT4_IM_MODULE=fcitx
XMODIFIERS=@im=fcitx
CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
QT_IM_MODULE=fcitx
Sorry idk how to write it in each line

Comment: CLUTTER_IM_MODULE=xim
it's the only one that parameter isn't fcitx

Comment: Ok, try this: `sudo apt install fcitx-frontend-gtk?`

Comment: It said :"unable to locate..."

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. i've really encountered problem with IM, i tried using Ibus before but it didn't work at all. I wanna use Opera 'cause it seem that use less memory than other, Messenger pop-up is great, so .

Comment: Then I suspect a typo. Did you include the trailing question mark at the end of the command? (It was my intention that you should.) It's the packages `fcitx-frontend-gtk2` and `fcitx-frontend-gtk3` I suggest that you install.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson i am new to Linux but i'm not naive as you said :/. these package are already newest version.

Comment: I didn't say (or mean) that you are naive. But if those packages are installed, I don't know which package(s) it's missing. Sorry.

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson  thank you for replying and being patient with me.